# Hyperlink in TreeView using javafx

Tags: javafx, hyperlink, treeview, tableview

I am using javafx for first time. I am using TableView and in 1 column TreeView is used.
Its root node is "Person (Joe,Jack)" and it has sub node like address, phone no etc. So now I want to give separate hyperlinks to Joe and Jack so that when they are clicked it redirects me to their friend lists. 
so it will be shown like :Person (*Joe*,*Jack*) but "Person" remains string and should not have hyperlink. This is how I want root node of TreeView.

```
String root_string = "Person";
HyperLink name1 = new Hyperlink("Joe");
HyperLink name2 = new Hyperlink("Jack");
root_string = root_string +"("+name1+","+"name2"+);

 TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<String>(root_string);
 root.setExpanded(true);
 root.getChildren().addAll(
     new TreeItem<String>("address"),
     new TreeItem<String>("phone")
 );
 TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<String>(root);
```

Here I want Person as simple string and Hyperlinks to Joe and Jack only..

Comment: Please, include shortest code necessary to reproduce your problem

Comment: Put the text "Person (" and then the appropriate links (buttons?) inside a VBox (which in itself will be inside the TreeView). [Check out the documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm)